# How to calculate the shortest distance between agents in a gis map

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm trying to implement a model in which vehicles move from a City agent `Cidade` to a Port agent `Porto`.

The parameters are loaded from a database - Ports: `latitude`  and `longitude`; City: `cidades`. There is a `City` agent type embedded in Main called `cidades`and there is a population of Port agents in Main called `portoes`.

Those parameters are used to define the position of the `City` and `Ports` agents in a `gis map` so that it is possible to map the distances between them

I'm using the `getNearestAgent` function to get the nearest agent from the collection. The body of the function is defined as `return getNearestAgent(main.portoes);`.

The function is returning the value of the nearest `Port` in relation to the first element of the `City` agent. What I'm trying to do in sequence is calculate the nearest `Port` to every `City` element, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please show us what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
LinkedHashMap<City,Port> nearestPortsFromCity=new LinkedHashMap<City,Port>();
    for(City city : cities){
        nearestPortsFromCity.put(city,getNearestAgent(findAll(main.ports,p->p.city.equals(city)));
    }
```

With that done, now you can access the nearest port from a city by doing

```
Port nearest=nearestPortsFromCity.get(theCity);
```